# GetContainerForItemOverride in UWP app

Tags: listview, uwp, listviewitem

I'm working on an app that uses a cross-platform third-party layout engine to place `UI elements` in the `Visual Tree` at specific coordinates (by putting things in canvases). In my scenario I need a virtualizing `ListView` where every item of it goes through this layout engine.

All is fine until I try to delete items from the list view. I've narrowed the issue down to the fact that for my list view I am returning a `Canvas` when GetContainerForItemOverride() is called, instead of returning a `ListViewItem`. But of course I need a `Canvas` so that the layout engine can put stuff at specific coordinates in the `Canvas`.

I've created a very dumb sample below that will reproduce the issue that I'm hitting. Basically when I try to delete an item by calling `.RemoveAt()` or `.Remove()` then I get an `InvalidCastException` (btw the same problem happens if I'm using an `ItemsSource` in this example instead of adding directly to `.Items`).

Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Here's the code

```
<Page x:Class="Sample.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:sample="using:Sample">

    <StackPanel>
        <sample:CustomListViewCrash x:Name="MyListViewCrash">
            <sample:CustomListViewCrash.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </sample:CustomListViewCrash.ItemsPanel>
        </sample:CustomListViewCrash>

        <Button Content="Delete" Tapped="Delete_OnTapped" />
    </StackPanel>

</Page>
```

And the code behind

```
public sealed partial class MainPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyListViewCrash.Items.Add("blah blah");
    }

    private void Delete_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyListViewCrash.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            MyListViewCrash.Items.RemoveAt(0);
        }

    }
}

public class CustomListViewCrash : ListView
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        var canvas = new Canvas
        {
            Width = 100,
            Height = 50
        };

        canvas.Children.Add(new Button());

        return canvas;
    }

    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        var canvas = (Canvas) element;
        var button = (Button) canvas.Children[0];
        button.Content = item;

        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    }
}
```

And here's the info about the exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException occurred
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Specified cast is not valid.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IVector`1.RemoveAt(UInt32 index)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.VectorToListAdapter.RemoveAtHelper[T](IVector`1 _this, UInt32 index)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.VectorToListAdapter.RemoveAt[T](Int32 index)
   at ReactiveDelete.MainPage.Delete_OnTapped(Object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) in MainPage.xaml.cs:line 31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception of "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid" , that container of the `ListView` should be the `ListViewItem`.

You should be able to set the `CustomListViewCrash` inherits from the `ItemsControl` to replace the `ListView`. When the `CustomListViewCrash` class inherits from the `ItemsControl`, the container of the `CustomListViewCrash` is not `ListViewItem`.

If you want your class inherits from the `ListView`, you should be able to set the `Canvas` to the `Content` of the `ListViewItem`. And we should be able to remove the `base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item)` method in the `PrepareContainerForItemOverride`.

For example:

```
public class CustomListViewCrash : ListView
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        var canvas = new Canvas
        {
            Width = 100,
            Height = 50
        };
        canvas.Children.Add(new Button());
        var listViewItem = new ListViewItem();
        listViewItem.Content = canvas;
        return listViewItem;
    }

    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        var listViewItem = (ListViewItem)element;
        var canvas = (Canvas)listViewItem.Content;
        var button = (Button)canvas.Children[0];
        button.Content = item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes doing what you said does solve the problem of not hitting the crash. I'm seeing some other rendering issues (flickering) with your approach though. But I think that might be related to my app so I'm marking this as the solution. Thanks.